# How to find the largest integer(s) between 3 integers

Tags: vb.net

I would like to find the largest integer(s) between 3 integers.

I could do this by nesting `If` statements. Since I have further code to write however this would be long and untidy.

I was wondering if there was an easier way to find the largest integer(s) (including if let's say `A` and `B` are equal but both higher than `C`).

P.S Can you do this with 2-D arrays?

Comment: Are they all going to be Integers/Doubles/Decimals? If not then isn't very easy.

Comment: They're all integers, however, I need to know which ones which.

Comment: Does the "further code" depend on *which* of the variable(s) is/are the maximum?

Comment: @AndrewMorton yes the "further code" does depend on which variable(s) is/are the maximum. I should've added that into the original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308959.aspx) to do this:

```
Dim numbers() As Integer = {1, 3, 5}

Dim max As Integer = numbers.Max()

Debug.Write("Max number in numbers() is " & max.ToString())
```

Output:

[image]

Edited as per conversation with OP on wanting to know which genre was ranked the best.

When asked *How do you get the data?* OP responds with:

> I have a text file containing movie|genre on every line. I read this and count which genre (out of 3) is the highest.

I have drafted up some code which reads from a text file and populates a class.

First let me show you the code:

```
Dim myFilms As New Films

Using sr As New IO.StreamReader("C:\films.txt")

    Do Until sr.Peek = -1

        Dim columns As String() = sr.ReadLine().Split(New Char() {"|"c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

        'columns(0) = film name
        'columns(1) = genre
        myFilms.Add(New Film(columns(0), columns(1)))
    Loop

End Using

If myFilms.Count > 0 Then
    Dim bestGenre = myFilms.GetBestGenre()

    'Go off and read the genre file based on bestGenre
End If
```

From the above code you can see the class `Films` being populated with a new `Film`. I then call a method from the `Films` class, but only if there are films to choose from. Let me show you the class structure for both these:

**Film:**

```
Public Class Film
    Public Key As String

    Public Sub New(ByVal filmName As String,
                   ByVal genre As String)

        _filmName = filmName
        _genre = genre

    End Sub

    Private _filmName As String
    Public ReadOnly Property FilmName As String
        Get
            Return _filmName
        End Get
    End Property

    Private _genre As String
    Public ReadOnly Property Genre As String
        Get
            Return _genre
        End Get
    End Property

End Class
```

**Films:**

```
Public Class Films
    Inherits KeyedCollection(Of String, Film)

    Protected Overrides Function GetKeyForItem(ByVal item As Film) As String
        Return item.Key
    End Function

    Public Function GetBestGenre() As String

        Return Me.GroupBy(Function(r) r.Genre).OrderByDescending(Function(g) g.Count()).First().Key

    End Function

End Class
```

I must note that although this code does work it may come unstuck if you have 2 or more genres which are joint top. The code still works however it only returns one of the genres. You may want to expand on the code to suit your needs based on that scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
Dim max As Integer
max = integer1

If integer2 > max Then
   max = integer2
End If

If integer3 > max Then
   max = integer3
End If
```

Not many more ways that I can think of off the top of my head to do this.

Comment: This can be shorten by assigning integer1 to max before the first if statement...

Comment: @David What about if integer 1 and 2 were the same and both over 3? Edit: Also, I need to know that max = integer3 rather than just giving me the highest number.

Comment: @Suhaib Yes, because `max = integer1` from the very start, in line 2. It only gets changed IF `integer2` is bigger. It's not, it's the same, so doesn't change it again. Likewise, `integer3` is smaller, so doesn't change it again.

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines will work for any number of integers.
Put the numbers into an array then use a `For[...]Next` statement to loop through the array comparing the current member with `max`. If `max` is lower, set it to the current member. When the loop terminates, `max` will contain the highest number:

```
Dim nums() As Integer = {1, 2, 3}
Dim max As Integer

For i = 0 To nums.Length - 1
    If max < nums(i) Then
        max = nums(i)
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Couldn't you alternatively just do `nums.max()` ?

Comment: Yes, comparison with @Bugs'* answer reveals me to be an old-skool, pre-Linq,  kind of guy. But in my defence, my suggested code is maybe more easily modifiable to include things like identification of the position in the array, or to deal with what happens when there is a tie for first place (which you mentioned in your question, but did not specify what should happen ) (*and he not only supplied a neat answer, but also tidied up _my_ layout and punctuation! a true gentleman!)

Comment: I see, I have 2 questions. Firstly, how can  this be modified to deal with a tie for first place?  And secondly, why did you do `nums.length - 1`  instead of `nums.length`?

Comment: A1. My first thought is that you would have to do two loops; first one as above to determine the max, then a second time to pick up every matching item, for instance adding its position to a list. What you do after that is up to you. A2. The array is zero based thus index runs 0,1,2 when length = 3